# new window when using tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a game for a user to choose a characters color and proceed to lead them through a maze. Originally I had the user input the name of their character and the direction they wanted them to go, but changed the input to use the arrow keys with tkinter. Now I am running into a problem because the tkinter opens a new window for its input.

```
import view,datetime,Tkinter as tk

def main():
   global root
   if __name__ == "__main__":
      view.root.update()
      command = raw_input( "choose a player:" )
      run1( command )
      view.root.update()
      while True:
          root = tk.Tk()
          print( "Press a key (Escape key to exit):" )
          root.bind_all( '<Key>', key )
          root.mainloop()
      root.withdraw()
      root.destroy()
      view.root.destroy()

main()
```

This shows what I imported and my main function.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but what is the purpose of the  while loop in your main function?

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, I'm pretty sure that's the issue. What happens when you close the game window, say, with a mouse?

Comment: I put in the while loop as an infinite loop. I took it out and it still does the same thing. I had it in my original program when I was prompting the user for an input of the character and the direction they wanted them to go so they could move around the game. It became unnecessary when I changed to the arrow keys.

Comment: When I start the game it opens the actual window I want which shows the character and maze but also another smaller window where I have to click in for character movement. When I close the secondary window I am given this error:
TclError: can't invoke "wm" command:  application has been destroyed

Comment: The line `root.mainloop()` blocks until the application is destroyed. Where is the code for your secondary window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you do this...

```
root = tk.Tk()
...
root.mainloop()
```

You're creating a brand new window. So of course when you use `bind_all` on this new window, that new window is the one that receives the input. I can't really tell what you're trying to do, but it's clear that this is why you see the behavior that you see.

Most of the time, you only want one `root` -- that's why it's called "root"! It seems like you should use `bind_all` on the `view.root` instance, not on this new root.

Also, as a side note, the flow of control is really weird in your code. Why is `if __name__ == '__main__'` *inside* the `main` function? Normally that would be at the top level of the module, and would *call* `main` itself.

Comment: I was doing a lot of stuff wrong there, thanks for the help. I had gotten the code to use the arrow keys and was using that root instead of the view.root I should have been using. My 16 lines above have now turned into 6 lines. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The `root = tk.Tk()` statement actually creates a new window and `root.mainloop()` maintains the control loop for the windows. If you add this code into a `while True:` several windows will be opened one by one.

Check the necessity of the `while True:`

Regards